# how to get soapUI (Ready-API) test coverage results using java?

Tags: java, automation, soapui, ready-api

I'm using SOAPUI - java service automation. I'm seeing coverage metrics in the readyAPI tool. but I want to get those reports or metrics using Java into my codebase

I explored couple of options, but I didn't get any right sight. I'm wondering if I able to collect those coverage information , I can use it in my own code base

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking if you can use ready api against a java service? If so, the answer is yes

Comment: Yes I'm using ready-api against java service. Can you help me how can I get the coverage?

Comment: I think you need to research the problem a little bit more. Please feel free to ask more specific questions in the future however. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask